# Which Ubuntu Cloud Image format should I use?

Tags: eucalyptus

I am looking for a starter image to test a new Eucalyptus 4.4.5 cloud.  I began here:

https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#image-guide/ig_task_eustore.html

but was directed to a URL that is not in service:

http://emis.eucalyptus.com/ (http://emis.eucalyptus.cloud doesn't work either)

I am trying, instead, to follow the imaging guide to build my own.  I'd like to achieve an HVM CentOS or Ubuntu image.  Based on reading I think one of their cloud releases is the best choice but I don't understand which format to choose.  Can anyone provide guidance on what filetype to choose from their cloud releases?:

Ubuntu: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/20190327/

CentOS: https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to pick one out from those cloud image repositories:

- **Ubuntu**: go for `amd64` images ending in `.img`
- **CentOS**: go for `x86_64` images with `raw` in name, possibly compressed

Or you could run this on the head node (with euca2ools installed):

`python <(curl -Ls https://eucalyptus.cloud/images)`

and you will be offered a menu of images known to work.

Comment: Thanks, that is the info I was hoping for!  On a side note I tried that python script first and it times out.  I am behind a proxy and have set a .wgetrc and .curlrc but it just hangs when it gets here: "Select an image Id from the following table: "

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The script uses `urllib` module to pull in a catalog file from githubusercontent.com. Apparently the module respects environment variable `http_proxy`. Perhaps try `export http_proxy='http://myproxy.example.com:1234'` before invoking the script?

Comment: Thank you.  The http_proxy export wasn't working for me which is why I moved on to the .wgetrc and .curlrc.  In any case no combination of the three seems to work.  I'll recheck my plumbing...

Comment: Could you explain exactly what the script does?  Specifically does it download from the OS publishers and then package using the Eucalyptus imaging guide commands?  Or is it a library of pre-packaged images that have already been wrapped up by the Eucalyptus software publishers.  If so it looks like it might try to automatically upload them to my Euca cloud.  Is there an option to download them instead?  The place where I can run the script without a proxy does not have access to the Euca cloud where the images need to be uploaded.

Comment: The images script on eucalyptus cloud reads a json format catalog (currently available here https://github.com/sjones4/eucalyptus-extras/tree/master/images) and converts (qcow) or directly uses (raw) the images with your eucalyptus cloud. The linked images are provided for download by the distributions and have a variety of update policies. You can manually download images using the urls in the catalog and later upload them to your eucalyptus cloud.